# Cannot get ArcGIS Server to provide an offline KMZ

Tags: arcgis-server, kmz

I have been trying to find a way to get ArcGIS Server to provide me with a KMZ file that has all the data and symbolization information contained within it (no network links). This way the KMZ can be loaded, displayed and edited on a device that most likely will not have connectivity back the original ArcGIS Server.

Has anyone figured out a way to do this?

Comment: Don’t know for certain, but based on the KMZ ArcGIS help topic it *only* talks about network links.  I’d infer that’s all you get. If you want a KMZ with the data you’d need to do an export of sorts

Comment: I contacted our Esri Tech Rep and he said that ArcGIS Server only uses network links. He recommend developing a GeoProcessing service to do this leveraging the Map to KML Tool.

Comment: Sounds like you got your answer, I'd suggest doing a self-answer and accepting it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The way to get a standalone KMZ file with all the symbolization is to hit the Query REST end point for each individual layer ('/0' .. '/n') in the MapServer service - specifying 'KMZ' as the output format. There is no way to get a single, standalone KMZ file with all the layers directly from ArcGIS Server; you would have to have client-side code that can intercept and merge all the KMZs into a single, mega KMZ.